# java https no verify certificate

Tags: java, https

I would like to connect to a test server in https from a java program I made. I don't want to verify anything in the certificate, how can I achieve this?

I am using:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(server).openConnection() );
                            connection.setDoOutput       (true);
                            connection.setDoInput        (true);
                            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
                            connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
          OutputStream        out  = connection.getOutputStream();
          OutputStreamWriter  wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
                              wout.write(xml);
                              wout.flush();
                              out .close();




          //READ RESPONSE.
          InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
```

But when I execute, I get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can acces https sites but Somesites wanted the certificate. So you can use under the codes. And you have to take certificate with InstallCert program.

```
String httpsURL = "https://www.google.com";
URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
                InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way..

```
URL url1;
try {
            url1 = new URL(url);

            if(url1.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https")){// you dont need this check
                try {
                HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {

                       public boolean verify(String urlHostName, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession session) {

                           if (urlHostName.equals(session.getPeerHost())) {
                               logger.info("Verified HTTPS "+session.getPeerHost()+"  >> "+ urlHostName);
                           } else {
                               logger.info("Warning: URL host "+urlHostName+" is different to SSLSession host "+session.getPeerHost());
                           }
                           return true;
                       }
                   };

                   TrustManager[] trustAll = new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] { new javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager() {

                       public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

                           return null;
                       }

                       public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

                       }

                       public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

                       }
                   } };

                   javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sc = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

                    sc.init(null, trustAll, new java.security.SecureRandom());

                   SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) sc.getSocketFactory();
                   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(factory);
                   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);

                    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)                 url1.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
```

Continue with your OutputStreamWriter write part.
You can do this without importing ssl certificate and without any third party support.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to get from https://IP/file, it'll return the error the IP is not verified

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and updated your answer with more information.